# How to optimize query which remove duplicates for 2 million items

Tags: mysql, sql

Good evening,

This is my query which should remove duplicates from table. How can I optimize this for two milion records?

```sql
DELETE p1 
FROM wp_ads_platform_users p1 
INNER JOIN wp_ads_platform_users p2 
WHERE p1.id < p2.id 
  AND p1.number = p2.number
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: What's the constraints on the table? What are the indexes? Why don't you think this is optimal?

Comment: Does it matter? You're only going to execute this query once, right?

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can pre-aggregate:

```
DELETE p
    FROM wp_ads_platform_users p JOIN
         (SELECT number, MAX(id) as max_id
          FROM wp_ads_platform_users p2
          GROUP BY number
         ) pp
         ON p.number = pp.number
    WHERE p.id < pp.max_id;
```

That said, deleting 2 million rows will take time.  You might want to recreate the table using a query.